# How to fetch current location of device when App is launched first time in windows 8.1 using c#?

Tags: c#, location, windows-8.1

I want to fetch current location when the app is launched for the first time. So I added following code in App.xaml.cs file but the problem I am facing that it is taking a lot of time to fetch the location. I think this happens because I didn't got a dialog to allow or block the location tracking.

```
var location=new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
Geoposition pos=await location.GetGeopositionAsync();
GetLocation.Lat = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude.ToString(); 
GetLocation.Long = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude.ToString();
```

The above code I have added in OnLaunched event in App.xaml.cs page and GetLocation is a class where I am storing current location.

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue ?

Comment: Can someone help or suggest some other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by first time you mean each time the application is opened (for a single position session), I tried a solution and worked for me.Using Windows.Devices.Geolocation, My code is as follows:

```
public async void MyLocationFinder()
    {
        Geolocator MyGeolocator = new Geolocator();
        MyGeolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;
        try
        {
            Geoposition MyGeoposition = await MyGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
               maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
               timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) );
            LatitudeTextBlock.Text = MyGeoposition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
            LongitudeTextBlock.Text = MyGeoposition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            //The app doesn't has the right capability or the location master switch is off
            StatusTextBlock.Text = "Location is Disabled in phone storage.";
        }
    }
```

You can call MyLocationFinder() method in OnLaunched function of the app.xaml.cs if you do so you'll have to remove the Textblock part from the code and you can replace it with any any variable declared globally to store it into the class in another method.

Comment: Have you tried in on launched event, because my code also works in app but doesn't work in app on launched method.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Yes I did try it out on the OnLaunched method it works just fine. Yes it does take like a few seconds to start the app but it works well (I just removed the statusTextBlock.Text with a message box). I also tried an alternative by using the same in the OnNavigated to method of the MainPage.xaml.cs and that worked too. please try the above solution in both the methods and let me know if it shows any errors or if it doesn't work or if it works please tick my answer as correct for future references.